# Regex expression to check if the string is valid

Tags: regex

I need help with creating a regex that can return if any of these options are valid.

TypeA:

- ############
- ############A
- ###########
- ###########A

TypeB:

- ###########
- ###########A
- ###########AA
- ##########A
- ##########AA

where # represents a digit and A an alphabet.  I really appreciate your help in the matter.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a regex. `return true` would work fine as you haven't given any rules as to why they shouldn't be valid.

Comment: basically, `^[0-9]{min,max}[a-zA-Z]{0,2}$`.

Comment: @thg435 - Not quite, `############A` is in the list but `############AA` isn't.  Try `^\d{12}[A-Za-z]?|\d{10,11}[A-Za-z]{0,2}$`

Comment: Thanks adamdc78. That worked but now I have to split them.

Comment: Would this work:

Type A - ^\d{11}\d?[A-Za-z]?

Type B - ^\d{9}\d?[A-Za-z]{0,2}?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
^\d{10,12}[A-Za-z]{0,2}$
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/nV8fM6

Based on your example, there are always either 10 or 12 digits and either 0, 1, or 2, alpha characters.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
\d{1,12}\w{0,2}
```

Based on the examples you gave you can have as many as 12 digits and as many as 2 characters.

That Regex could even be:

```
\d{1,12}[A-Z]{0,2}
```

so that it *only* allows capital letters.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JKadjlOa2AhAA-Ho)